# Integrate Google OpenID with Swagger in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, swagger, google-oauth

I want to authenticate in my application using Google OpenID. I added authentication in Swagger, but after successfully  redirection, login and redirection back to my Swagger, requests are only send access_token in header, but not id_token which is supposed to include e.g. user email (I used https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope). Is there an option to get this id_token to correctly authenticate in .NET app? I'm using implicit flow right now. There is my Swagger configuration:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {  
            {  
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme {  
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference {  
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,  
                        Id = "oauth2"  
                    },  
                    Scheme = "oauth2",  
                    Name = "authorization",  
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header  
                },  
                new List <string> ()  
            }  
        });   
        
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                Implicit= new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {
                            $"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",  
                            "Get email"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The request looks following:
[Request with access_token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Iil.png)

I read that there is a possibility to change default authorization parameter in Swagger. So after adding following configuration:

```
            Extensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>
            {
                {
                    "x-tokenName", new OpenApiString("id_token")
                }
            }
```

result was still inappropriate:
[Request with id_token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i61oH.png)

Comment: Are you sure your not confusing authencation with authorization?

Comment: Maybe i'm using wrong name but i want to get id_token from external provider (Google) and make request to my own API. Google have to define my identity. I don't want to give any access to Google Drive or Gmail. I only want to define who i am. So i think that it is authentication.

Comment: Then you want identity not oauth.  But why hook it to swagger?  swager tests rest api endpoints. you cant have signin to an api endpoint.  That would be Oauth2

Comment: I have only one endpoint which required only authenticated user (not permissions) via Google or Azure. I've done whole process via Azure, but i can't via Google. The rest of endpoints work different and there are different scheme applied. We don't take care of this endpoints right now.